# File must be created when cronjob runs

Tags: scripting

I need a bash script that creates different filenames when cronjob runs. Filename should be like `file1`, `file2`, `file3`. For example If Nov 1 Cron runs it should create `file1`, for November2 it should create `file2`.

Comment: So the file-name is related to the date?

Comment: Two interesting issues: [A] Does your cronjob only run once a day? [B] What happens on 1st December? Simple answer is to make a filename with: `file$( date '+%-d' )`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you re executing the script from a cron job is irrelevant. The script just needs to create a value that contains the day's day of month in it, and use it as a filename.

Getting the day's day of month is not as trivial as it first may sound.  In `bash` (release 4.2+) on Linux, this can be done with

```bsh
printf -v filename 'file%(%-e)T' -1
```

... where `%(...)T` is how a time format string may be used with `printf` to format a timestamp, and where `%e` is the day of month as an integer.  Normally, `%e` would contain an initial space character if the day is a single digit day, but using `%-e` left-aligns this digit so that the space disappears.

This does not work on (some) non-Linux systems though, and instead you get the filename `file-e`. So on those systems, it would be better to use `%d` to get a zero-filled day, like `08`, or `02`.  This is also preferable if you want the filenames to sort nicely in the shell when you list them.

```bsh
printf -v filename 'file%(%d)T' -1
```

On systems with older `bash` implementations, such as macOS (unless a newer `bash` has been installed via e.g. Homebrew), you will need to call the `date` external command:

```bsh
printf -v filename 'file%s' "$(date +%d)"
```